# Can't call JS function from file Drupal 5

Tags: javascript, drupal

I'm working on Drupal 5. I have a separate .js file which is added by using

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','MTM')."/include/JS_form.js");
```

I have an element

```
<a onclick="MTM_test()">Name&#8657;</a>
```

And a JS code in JS_form.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MTM_test(){
alert('A');
}

</script>
```

And when I click on that element nothing happens even though it appears on the page's source code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your js file, remove the `<script>` tag for it is not necessary since it is already a js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS file contains HTML tags. You have to remove the tags.

JavaScript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  // <<==== REMOVE THIS!
        function MTM_test(){
            alert('A');
        }
  </script> // <<=== REMOVE THIS!
```